# JavaScript Arrays into Array of object problem

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am getting data from API, but the format is not good for me. So would like to convert 2 arrays of strings into one with the object.

```
const arr1 = ['Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday']

const arr2 = ['02 August 2022', '02 August 2022', '02 August 2022', '02 August 2022', '02 August 2022', '02 August 2022', '02 August 2022', '02 August 2022', '02 August 2022']
```

And I would like to have something like :

```
const newArr = [ { day:arr1[0], date:arr2[0] }, { day:arr1[1], date:arr2[2]} , ... ]
```

Comment: 'And I would like to' see your attempt at fixing this. SO isn't a free coding service.

Comment: [Loops/iteration documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).

Answer (score 2):

Straight to the point.

```
function APIDataToMyObject(dayArr, dateArr){
  return dayArr.map((day, index) => ({day, date: dateArr[index]}));
}
```